# float center content with left fixed logo

Tags: css

Sorry, just can't get this'

Here: http://www.crownoilfield.com/ it looks as I want, except that for a browser window below 1040px, where the top logo floats below the company name.

```
<div id="top_wide">
   <div id="crownlogo"><img name="crown_logo6p32" src="images/crown_logo6p32.gif" >
   </div>
   <div id="top">
      <div id="logo"> <img src="images/crown_oilfield_svc_4.png" ></div>

#top_wide {
color:#474327;
    font-size:36px;
}
#crownlogo {
float:left;
padding:0px;
padding-left:5px;
display: table-cell;
}
#crownlogo img {
margin:0;
    }   
#top {
    position:relative;
height:82px; 
width:1040px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
display: inline-block;
display: table;
}
#logo {
width:620px;
float:left;
color:#474327;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:xx-large;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:-77px;
```

}

Thanks,
ed

Comment: What browser does this happen in? Firefox, and IE look fine when I reduce the window.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#top {
    position: relative;
    height: 82px;
    width: 1040px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 165px;
    clear: right;
}
#logo {
    width: 620px;
    float: left;
    color: #474327;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: xx-large;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it. The result is that it still slides under; just now the company name can slide left of the window!

Comment: I hope have understood what you wanted to do

Comment: I think the desired behavior is that the window will open a slider when it gets smaller than 1040px+the logo width. But I can't ever recall seeing it done, so maybe its not possible.

Comment: OK, that did it. Sort of! The intended effect was that the company name float with the body of the page--until it collided with the logo at which point a slider would appear. Your way, the company name stays put regardless of window size--it's not centered with the page content. But its better than what I had.

Comment: great! yes may be you have to edit some other styles to get the title centered. I only focus on the company name. ;)